# Is the address returned by vmalloc() a multiple of PAGE_SIZE?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'd like to ask a question about `vmalloc()`.

According to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/core-api/mm-api.html?highlight=vmalloc#c.vmalloc) from kernel.org, it says:

> Allocate enough pages to cover size from the page level allocator and map them into contiguous kernel virtual space.

**Does that mean the (starting) address returned by `vmalloc()` will be a multiple of PAGE_SIZE?**

Below is my thoughts:

I have tried to call `vmalloc()` and printed out the address in hexadecimal. The last three bits are all zeros, and the value of PAGE_SIZE is 4096 on my system, which, kind of proves my assumption. Besides, in `mmap()`,

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
                  int fd, off_t offset);
```

and the manpage also says,

> If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the (page-aligned)
> address at which to create the mapping; this is the most portable
> method of creating a new mapping.  If addr is not NULL, then the
> kernel takes it as a hint about where to place the mapping; on
> Linux, the kernel will pick a nearby page boundary (but always
> above or equal to the value specified by
> /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr) and attempt to create the mapping
> there.

> offset must be a multiple of the page size

> A file is mapped in multiples of the page size.

The above seems to prove my assumption, but I am not quite sure. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Yep, "page-aligned" means the address returned is a multiple of PAGE_SIZE.

Comment: @wxz: “Page-aligned” is quoted from the `mmap` documentation, not the `vmalloc` documentation.

Comment: Re “The last three bits are all zeros”: Presumably you mean the last three hexadecimal digits are zeros, so the last 12 bits are zeros.

Comment: How is the alignment of `vmalloc` related to `mmap`? They're different things, but IIRC they might share some code paths.

Comment: What about kmalloc()? Is the address returned by kmalloc() also a multiple of PAGE_SIZE?

Comment: @Sagar: When implementing mmap(), we need to know the physical frame number of the page we want to map, vmalloc_to_pfn() could help us do this.

Comment: @EthanL., I agree with that statement, but mmap doesn't really have a direct relation to vmalloc. They _might_ share underlying code-paths, but the interface provided by one has nothing to do with the interface provided by the other.

Comment: @EthanL., kmalloc is either naturally aligned or aligned to ARCH_KMALLOC_MINALIGN, depending on the allocation size ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/core-api/memory-allocation.rst)).

Comment: @Sagar: Yeah, I get what you mean, there's limited relation between mmap in user space and vmalloc in kernel space. When I was posting the question, I did not think too much on it - that's why I mentioned mmap().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vmalloc` allocates pages and returns the starting address of the allocated memory. Every page is necessarily page-aligned. Therefore the starting address is a multiple of the size of a page.